# How to get rid of using --user in pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pycharm, package, ubuntu-18.04

I use to own a laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 and installing packages through the pycharm terminal with pip was a simple `pip install foobar_package`. Recently I replaced my laptop with a desktop and installed Ubuntu 18.04 on it as well. The problem I face is that when I run the default `pip install` command it tries to install the packages in the root python directory.

The internet gave a solution in which I should just add `--user` to the `pip` command. 
For example: `pip install --user foobar_package`. Although this works it is frustrating following a tutorial that require 5 pip packages to be installed and I have to insert the --user command manually whereas previously it was a simple copy and paste.

Can I setup pycharm terminal to always use the home user to install the packages in the venv?

Comment: The following does not make sense to me: "_Can I setup pycharm terminal to always use the home user to install the packages in the venv?_". Would you mind clarifying this bit? There's to my understanding no point in using a _venv_ to install packages in the user's _home_ directory.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has been solved in the *pip* version that (coincidentally) has been released earlier this week *20.0 (2020-01-21)* (but this version has an issue so make sure to install *20.0.1*).

See the [release notes for *pip 20.0*](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#features):

> Default to doing a user install (as if --user was passed) when the main site-packages directory is not writeable and user site-packages are enabled. ([#1668](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1668))

Comment: @SandMan Does that answer your question? Any clarification needed?